# negative user feedback warning : any way to narrow down specific posts?

Tags: facebook, feedback

We've received an automated message "Our systems have flagged your app <> for receiving a high amount of negative user feedback. Accordingly, we might be forced to place a temporary restriction on your app in order to protect the user experience on Platform. We ask you to promptly address this issue within 48 hours of the sending of this notice, after which our automated systems will evaluate your app once again. Please note we reserve the right to take action against your app even before the end of this 48 hour period.

Specifically, users are responding negatively to Stream stories from their friends using your app."

We're struggling to triage and rectify this ASAP. We're not aware of any engineering change that would introduce an issue and we manage a news-style website from which a user can share any number of stories. BUT we can't find anything in insight that gives us an idea if a specific story was shared and is the root cause of being reported as spam.

IS anybody aware of how one might "drill down" within insight and get down to the metadata regarding the specific posts being flagged/reported?

Comment: any of those things that I see in my stream from other users that if I click on asks for all kinds of details I consider spam

Comment: The question still remains as to if there are any avenues I can pursue to better understand the specific source of the spike. In simple terms, one of hundreds of possible articles was shared via Facebook from one friend to multiple friends, likely many many times, and that story was flagged as spam. Which in turn slaps *our* hand for something we didn't do. It's like saying that because lots of friends are recommending a movie to others that don't like the movie, the theater is being closed.

Comment: sometimes people just think people are doing bogus apps on facebook, they simply feel like spam, so they mark it as spam, even though they could take other options.  People are thinking / feeling people, they don't work according to facebook guidelines.

Comment: the question remains off topic and not suitable for stackoverflow

Comment: Hmmmm, I went through developer.facebook.com to try and find resources that might assist, which lead me to https://developers.facebook.com/support/community/, and the community reference : "Facebook Engineers regularly answer questions on StackOverflow, and there's a great community of active developers there who can help you. Facebook On StackOverflow"

So I was expecting this *was* on topic and suitable.

Perhaps I'm not understanding the context of the developer section's reference to the contrary.

Comment: possibly.... read the faq for this site, this is all about coding questions.

Comment: In the insights, under negative feedback, stream publish, there is a dropdown list where you can select each individual stream story (assuming you used the ref= field).  I'm in the same boat right now only there is no negative feedback showing in insights yet they suspended my requests ability.